# Update array state in functional components using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to update the `cars` array whenever the **Add** button is clicked. I see that new object is added to `updatedCars` array but when I try to set the state with it, the `cars` state won't get updated.

I still see the initial state even after adding a new object in the array.

```
export default function App() {
  const [cars, setCars] = useState([{ name: "Audi", type: "sedan" }]);
  
  const handleAdd = () => {
    const newCar = { name: "Benz", type: "sedan" };
    const updatedCars = [...cars, newCar];
    console.log("updatedCars", updatedCars);
    setCars(updatedCars);
    console.log("result", cars);
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleAdd}>Add</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I created a working example using [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-morse-h4ln0?file=/src/App.js:65-508). Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

`setCars` is the asynchronous method, and you can't get the updated value of `cars` immediately after `setCars()`

```
setCars(updatedCars);
console.log(cars); //This will console old value of `cars`
```

You should use `useEffect` with adding a `cars` dependency to check updated value.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(cars);
}, [cars]);
```